# How to fix scss file import error on angular Nativescript app

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, nativescript

I'm working on a NativeScript app and I'm using scss for styling.
The app was working well but it started showing me an error concerning a certain scss file.

Error message:

[image]

here is the folder containing my _colors.scss file:

[image]

file _colors.scss file content :

[image]

and I'm importing it in the other scss files like this (depending on the directory) :

[image]

all the import directories are fine, I don't see why this 'Could not resolve' error keeps showing.

I've tried restarting the app and deleting the (hooks, node_modules and platformes) files and running 'npm install' again.

Let me know if you need more clarifications.

Comment: Did you try `@import "~/theme/_colors";`, assuming theme folder is at root level.

Comment: it couldn't detect this directory, my _colors.scss file is on the same level as app folder

Comment: I've changed the directory to '/src/theme/colors' and it works now, altough it shows an error message on the console which says : Error: /src/theme/colors does not start with /data/data/org.nativescript.nsngcourse/files/app
Got any idea about that ?